# Get month name from date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How to fetch month name from a given date in Oracle?

If the given date is `'15-11-2010'` then I want `November` from this date.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Month') from dual
```

in your example will be:

```
select to_char(to_date('15-11-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') from dual
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this,

```
select to_char(sysdate,'dd') from dual; -> 08 (date)
select to_char(sysdate,'mm') from dual; -> 02 (month in number)
select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy') from dual; -> 2013 (Full year)
```

Comment: This is correct but does not answer the question *How to fetch month **name***.

Answer (score 21):

`to_char(mydate, 'MONTH')` will do the job.

Answer (score 20):

In Oracle (atleast 11g) database :

If you hit

```
select to_char(SYSDATE,'Month') from dual;
```

It gives unformatted month name, with spaces, for e.g. May would be given as 'May     '. The string May will have spaces.

In order to format month name, i.e to trim spaces, you need

```
select to_char(SYSDATE,'fmMonth') from dual;
```

This would return 'May'.

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to pull the value from a field, you could use:

```
select extract(month from [field_name])
from [table_name]
```

You can also insert day or year for the "month" extraction value above.

Comment: this will just give month values but not the text.

Answer (score 5):

**if you are taking system date:**

```
--Full month name :
select to_char(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH'),'MONTH') as month from dual; --MARCH    
--Short month name:
select to_char(trunc(sysdate,'MON'),'MON') as month from dual; --MAR
--Month number:
select to_char(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),'MM') as month from dual;  --03
```

**if you are taking a specific date:**

```
--Full month's name:
select to_char(trunc(to_date('11-03-2021','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MONTH'),'MONTH') as month from dual; --MARCH
--Short month's name:
select to_char(trunc(to_date('11-03-2021','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MON'),'MON') as month from dual; --MAR
--Month's number:
select to_char(trunc(to_date('11-03-2021','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MM'),'MM') as month from dual;  --03
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select to_char(SYSDATE,'Month') from dual;
```

for full name and try this

```
select to_char(SYSDATE,'Mon') from dual;
```

for abbreviation

you can find more option here:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php