# Extracting the month of the date in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need help in extracting the month of the date in a certain column.
For example the whole table is called `A` and the column for date is called `END_TIME` which has a format like this `MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS`.

I want my output to be the name of the month.

Comment: Hint: one way to use extract function. https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/oracle-extract/

Comment: If END_TIME is, as it _should_ be, of data type DATE, then no it does not have the format you show, or any other "format".  It's "format" is oracle's internal binary format for DATE.  What you show is a character-string representation of the date, as produced by either an explicit or implicit use of the TO_CHAR function.  For more, see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: Yes, the format I showed is a string representation. I'm not sure if that is the default format in oracle or not. But that's the data I get whenever I extract.

Answer (score 1):

If `END_TIME` column's datatype is `DATE` (should be, looks like it is), then you should apply `TO_CHAR` function to it with desired format mask. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table a as select sysdate end_time from dual;

Table created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From a;

END_TIME
-------------------
13.08.2020 08:51:04

SQL> select to_char(end_time, 'Month', 'nls_date_language = english') mon from a;

MON
---------
August

SQL>
```

Comment: what does "from dual" do?

Comment: DUAL is a SYS-owned one-row, one-column table, frequently used in Oracle when running SELECT statements against an "unknown" source table.

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty starightforward you can make use of to_char function like below.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MONTH') FROM DUAL;
```

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497456/get-month-name-from-date-in-oracle#:%7E:text=to_char(mydate%2C%20%27MONTH%27)%20will%20do%20the%20job.&text=select%20to_char(SYSDATE%2C%27Month%27)%20from%20dual%3B,string%20May%20will%20have%20spaces.)

Comment: I tried this 
select to_char(END_TIME, 'MONTH') FROM vwafer;

vwafer is where the column END_TIME is located. But it's not working.

Comment: You are working on Oracle and what you get ?