# month number to month text in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that shows the number of flights each month, but the month appears in number format and I want to convert the month number as text.

Here is the query:

```
select to_char(f.departuretime, 'yyyy-mm') month, count(*) numberofflights
from flight f
group by to_char(f.departuretime, 'yyyy-mm')
order by numberofflights desc;
```

output:

```
MONTH       NUMBEROFFLIGHTS
2022-05     7
2022-11     5
2022-08     3
...         ...
```

I want to display the months like "2022-MAY" or just "MAY" and so on.

Comment: Educate yourself and read about Datetime format models (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924); it's all in there.

Comment: Use format model yyyy-MON

Comment: Or actually - what do you need for August? AUG or AUGUST?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get month name from date in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497456/get-month-name-from-date-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `month` format instead of `MM` to get the month's name instead of its number:

```sql
select to_char(f.departuretime, 'yyyy-MONTH') month, count(*) numberofflights
from flight f
group by to_char(f.departuretime, 'yyyy-MONTH')
order by numberofflights desc;
```

Comment: That will return the month as "may      " and "august    " for example (including many trailing spaces!) instead of "MAY" and "AUG".

Comment: @mathguy good catch, thanks. Fixed.